# When using the patch method, I get an error: "PATCH" not allowed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I study Rest framework and faced with a problem: detail": "Method "PATCH" not allowed. I do everything according to the documentation. I want update only fields: first_name and password.

views

```
class UpdateUserSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
   serializer_class = UserSerialize

   def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
       return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

serialize

```
class UserSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
   password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('first_name', 'password',)
```

routers

```
router.register(r'^updateuser', views.UpdateUserSet, base_name=User)
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the `urls.py` so we could see how you bind the viewset to paths? +  I don't think that this is the problem, but note that the `partial_update` method you have implemented doesn't do anything but return a response.

Comment: Yes, I know what my UpdateUserSet does not return anything, and I updated the code above

Comment: lastly, which URL did you try to PATCH? make sure that it was updateuser/{id}/

Comment: So, I add 'print(1)'  after permission_classes and I see it in the terminal. If rename 'partial_update' to 'patch(self, request, pk=None)' then I get 201 first status. Why does not it work as specified in the documentation? I now don't know how to call a method update in serializers.py..

Comment: I add method update in the serializer but he not call

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your URL is correct? When making a PATCH or PUT call to the endpoint, you have to pass in the identifier for the object. So instead of

`/api/books/`

pass in

`/api/books/1/`